# Why wouldn't you use Async responses for all resources in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm combing over the JAX-RS spec.  Everything seems simple enough. But I'm left with the question.  Why wouldn't I do this everywhere?  In otherwords, what are the downsides?  Since most resource requests end up hitting the DB, wouldn't you want all of them to be Async?

What are the downsides that I should be aware of?  Is there a bunch of extra overhead?  I haven't been able to find anything that says why you shouldn't do this, just how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not about `Async` feature of `JAX-RS`, it is about `synchronous` vs `asynchronous` operations.

As you know `synchronous` operations use single `thread` to execute the task where as `asynchronous` operations require creation of additional `thread` to execute the task. Now, this is the overhead - creation of a new `thread`, executing task in new `thread` and then destroying that `thread`. This overhead results in performance.

Although, you can reuse already created `threads` instead of always creating new `thread`. But, still additional thread exists which impacts performance.

For example, a `synchronous web service` which processes around 1000 parallel `requests`. So, for handling these `requests`, 1000 `threads` will get created. Now, consider the same situation in `asynchronous` environment. For handling 1000 parallel `requests`, 2000 `threads` will get created - 1000 for handling `requests` and 1000 for `asynchronous` operation processing.

Now, you can understand the load on the operating system. High load will impact the performance. If the task is expensive i.e. takes time to execute, overall turn around time will decrease compare to `synchronous` execution. However, if the task is not expensive like db operations. overall turn around time will increase compare to `synchronous` execution. This is due to overhead of handling additional threads.

Another reason is complexity, `asynchronous` is always complex, requires additional code for making things `asynchronous`. However, framework like `Jersey` hides this complexity up to some extent.

So, it is always recommended to process expensive operations i.e the operations whose execution will take time, in `asynchronous` way so that overall turn around time can be decreased. `Asynchronous` execution for each operation is not recommended.